# Burn [two-columns]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

At the moment there are [137](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/two-columns) [two-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/two-columns) posts. It has no wiki/info. Coming from the [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) world, only 10 are also tagged with [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r).

Maybe it makes more sense in other worlds...

Comment: This might come as a shock to you but Stack Overflow isn't only about [tag:R] ...

Comment: @rene No shock at all, thanks, hence, discussion tag.

Comment: You might want to go over the [4 criteria](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) and apply them to that tag to get some more rationale why this tag should go. I personally think it could work well for CSS and HTML so maybe only clean-up is needed

Comment: @rene thanks, that makes sense, tidied up [r] tags.